# Join attributes table tool does not recognize non spatial data to execute

Tags: qgis, table

I'm using the graphical modeler in QGIS 2.4 to automate some processes and certain tools are basicaly necessaries to get to the point.
The "Join attributes table" tool, despite it's basic, can help us solve many problems!

Well, I need to join some information of a dbf table (non spatial data) with attributes of a shapefile (spatial data). However, I realized that this tool does not recognize my dbf file as a layer to execute the process.

I wonder this is some kind of bug from the software, because using spatial and non spatial data for this procedure is something basic, and everyday needed.

Can't use plugins, because it's not possible to use them in the graphical modeler (such as I know).

I would like to know if I'm using the correct tool, because I didn't found another tool in QGIS 2.4 for this procedure, or if there is another way to do it.